# When two different people help me arrive at the answer, how do I choose who to check-mark?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027202/how-to-query-the-database-table-with-no-primary-key) question. I got two really great answers - one person gave me the relevant code, but the other person gave me an explanation of why my solution actually wouldn't work, and how to get around it. Though the top-rated answer didn't have any code, which would've required a bit of researching and tinkering on my part, it certainly explained things better.

I guess the reason I'm asking is because Person A and Person B both helped me to an equal degree. If I'd only gotten Person B's answer, I would've had to go searching to figure out *why* I legitimately couldn't do what I wanted to do. If I'd only gotten Person A's answer, I would've had to go searching to figure out *how* to implement his solution.

So who should I give the check-mark to?

Comment: What I do is accept the better of the two answers, but upvote both and possibly comment on the unaccepted answer that it helped me fix my issue. That way, future readers have a flagpost that says both were helpful.

Comment: Which of the answer actually provided you with what you needed to answer your question?

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau I guess that in the strictest sense, Person B's answer gave me everything I needed to solve my problem. Another user could come by and figure out how to replicate it by looking at the code fairly easily. I just didn't want Person A's answer to float off-screen, because it has *really* good information in it.

Comment: Seeing how the other answer already received more votes, it won't be out of view for a while, unless more answers get even more upvotes.

Comment: Fair point, thanks. If you make an actual answer, rather than comments, I'll mark it for ya.